# Tracking how long a window was open in Java

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to track how long in milliseconds my JPanel was open, and I have no idea if there's an easier way to do it, but I thought I'd record the current time in MS on windowOpened(), and then subtract it from the time when the panel is closed? Unfortunately, I have no idea how to pass this variable.

Here's my code:

```
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
  Calendar OlCDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
  long openedTime = OlCDateTime.getTimeInMillis();
  System.out.println(openedTime);
}
```

I guess that I'm using a local variable not accessible outside the method, but I'm not sure how to fix that. Any advice on how to do that or a better way of doing what I'm trying to do would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Why? 2) Do you have a question? 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Comment: I did ask the question: how do I pass the variable outside windowOpened, or alternatively is there a better way to track how long a window was open? Not sure why I have to tell you /why/ I want to track how long the window was open to get an answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply save the time as an instance variable in the class?

Comment: 1)  Add a '?' to questions. 2)  You don't ***have to*** do ***anything.*** *"to get an answer."*  Uh-huh, but consider.. a) You have to maintain the interest of the audience long enough to get that answer.   b) You might be approaching the right goal ('why?') using the wrong strategy ('track how long panel is open'). --  But then, I don't understand why I need to explain any of this.  Surely your interest in getting an answer would make any request for further information welcome. O_o

Comment: A question requires neither a question mark nor an upwards inflection of the voice, it turns out. I'm sorry that you couldn't parse a question from the obvious question-eliciting call at the end. Nonetheless, thanks to jheddings for helping me out.

Comment: sounds like you need to read up on some java language basics (f.i. in the tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki)

Comment: You're not wrong. The problem is that I'm trying to assemble a program in a weekend for a lab experiment and I don't know java. Heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an instance variable in your class to accomplish this.  Simply track when the window was opened and when it was closed; then provide a method to access the information you need.  It might look something like this (simplified version):

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    // ...

    private long _openTime = 0;
    private long _closeTime = 0;

    public long getOpenTime() {
        long closed = _closeTime;

        // if the window is still open, use current time...
        if (closed == 0) {
            closed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        return (closed - _openTime);
    }

    public void onWindowOpened(WindowEvent evt) {
        _openTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void onWindowClosed(WindowEvent evt) {
        _closeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(getOpenedTime());  // DEBUG
    }
}
```

This allows the "opened time" to be accessed as long as the object remains valid.  This would include any caller who has subscribed for events on this object.